# Error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' using AWS API Gateway

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, flask, cors, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to make an `$ajax` request (POST) from my client-side (javascript/browser) to my API (python/flask) through AWS API Gateway. However, I get an error : `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`.

I have no problem when I request my API from `postman`.

I cannot enable option `jsonp` in ajax on my client side since it doesn't work at all.

So, I've tried to enable cors on API Gateway but my route is a `http proxy integration` (Method ANY) so according to AWS Docs, I have to enable Cors in the app itself. So, I did it but that didn't fix the problem.

In my python/flask app i added this:

```
@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    return response
```

But it still doesn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you add the API gateway permission?

Comment: I am not sure what it is ? add where ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have a CORS error issue.

First, go to your API Gateway and go to your resource, for example `/books`, then click on Actions and click activate the CORS like this:

[image]

Then fill all the options like this:

[image]

The Access-Control-Allow-Headers should have this: `'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'`

Also in the response of your python code you should add this too:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*"
```

Just remember the * is usually used on dev, but you should add the domain where the request will come to the API

Comment: I already did that. Actually I think the cors error rather come from an authorizer lambda function. I am not sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `'*'`, try to set set the effective origin to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.headers.origin)
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
```

> For most headers, the value `'*'` only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without `HTTP` cookies or `HTTP` authentication information).
>
> see [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) etc.

According to [CORS and caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#cors_and_caching), you may also have to add the following header.

```
response.headers.add('Vary', 'Origin')
```

Further you may have to define `xhrFields.withCredentials: true` when submitting the request with [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```
$.ajax({
   url: a_cross_domain_url,
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
   ...
});
```

Comment: I have an error : `response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.headers.origin)
2022-05-27T12:58:40.681710+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: 'EnvironHeaders' object has no attribute 'origin'`